# SAS-problems in line graphs making

Tags: graph, sas

I have a dataset about the distribution of frequency and I use following codes to create a line graph. However, the graph clearly has some problem. Could someone give me some suggestions?

```
proc gplot data=test;
title1 "AXP";
plot AXP*Date_l_;
symbol1 c=black v=star i=join;;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Use SGPLOT not GPLOT for starters. You appear to have some issues with your date variable so I'd sort that out first, make sure it's a SAS date with valid date values.

Comment: What sort of graph are you trying to produce? Please post a sketch or a link to an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your problem is the format of your date variable. SAS appears to think it's a number rather than a date. I suggest trying:

```
data test2;
  format Date2 Date8.;
  set test;
  Date2 = input(put(Date_l_,$8.),B8601DA8.);
run;
```